# SKRecognizer returns empty array

Tags: ios, speech-recognition

I'm using Dragon mobile NDEV SDK, but I have a problem with recognition.
In the root view a button is here to start recording. User can select a row with voice in my table view and then my app push to the corresponding view. But in this view when user press record button again SKRecognizer returns always an empty array, in the second view and even in the first if user go back with back button.
I must restart app to use SKRecognizer again.
Same if I go straight to the second view and I use SKRecognizer, working on this view but if I navigate recognition is not working.

I have a dedicated class for Dragon recognizer, and I instantiate this class in each view with a property for each one.

```
- (IBAction)recordAction:(id)sender
{
    if (_recognizer) {
        [_recognizer release];
    }
    _recognizer = [[DragonRecognizer alloc] init];

    [_recognizer startRecord];
}
```

And the SKRecognizer delegate:

```
- (void)recognizer:(SKRecognizer *)recognizer didFinishWithResults:(SKRecognition *)results
{
    long numOfResults = [results.results count];

    transactionState = TS_IDLE;

    if (numOfResults > 0)
        _result = [[results firstResult] lowercaseString];

    [_recognizer release];
    _recognizer = nil;

    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc postNotificationName:DragonReconizerFinishWithResults object:nil];
}
```

I receive notification in the view controller:

```
- (void)stopRecordReconizer:(NSNotification *)n
{
    if (![self.navigationController.visibleViewController isKindOfClass:[self class]])
        return;

    NSString *mainResult = [_recognizer result]; // No result
}
```

Do you know why SKRecognizer send me an empty array after second usage ?

Thanks for you're help !

Comment: I found my problem, I have a conflict between two APIs : one with audio player and Dragon for recording.
So this conflict give me that error : `<CAListenerProxy> AURemoteIO::ChangeHardwareFormats: error -10875`